# Python Lotto Simulation Random Error Occurrence

Tags: python, simulation

I made a python lotto simulation for a school project thing. I finally finished it and it works, it's just there is a random error that occurs when the user asks the computer to generate the numbers. If you try the code and keep restarting the program after pressing "1" for the computer to generate you will experience the same error. 
I would just like some help on fixing this error and maybe and adjustments I can make to the code.

Thanks

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Lotto\combined.py", line 154, in <module>
    start()
  File "D:\Lotto\combined.py", line 148, in start
    computer_generates()
  File "D:\Lotto\combined.py", line 83, in computer_generates
    list_of_Num_2[-1].append(x) #Loop and take the first number in list [-1] and add to list
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

[Python Lotto Simulation code on Github](https://gist.github.com/milddev/7a81928b970b375f118c94b652d64f02)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you have questions about code, it's best to paste the code into your question itself.   Indent the code by four spaces to format it properly.   Even *better*, narrow down and reproduce your problem in a smaller set of code, focusing on line 83 in your program.

Comment: Where are you trying to add `list_of_Num_2[-1]` to in line 83?

Comment: Because as the error says, you are accessing an int, `list_of_Num_2[-1]`, and trying to append an integer to it, which is incorrect syntax. I assume you have the same error in line 74 and your test or random number generator did not go into that loop to throw an error.

Comment: i dont understang